# how to install sqlbuddy in xampp package?

Tags: php, installation

Where to put `sqlbuddy` folder in `xammp` package?

what are the files we need to make changes?

```
My xampp path: d:\xampp

sqlbuddy folder path : d:\xampp\htdocs\sqlbuddy
```

Tried to access like 'localhost/xampp/sqlbuddy'  in the browser.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [SQL Buddy](http://sqlbuddy.com/) and put it inside in your XAMPP htdocs folder.

Access it from browser using this url, `http://127.0.0.1/sqlbuddy` or `http://localhost/sqlbuddy`